# How can a human being be a part of useful endeavor?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

http://www.econedlink.org/lessons/EconEdLink-print-lesson.php?lid=556&type=educator

> the students will identify useful endeavors they can be a part of.

How can a human being be a part of *useful endeavor*? We just can do useful endeavor, and we can be a part of, say, a crowd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The meaning of *endeavor* is

- earnest and industrious effort, especially when sustained over a period of time
- an enterprise or undertaking.

I would understand *to be part of the endeavor* as *to be part of the effort*.
It could also mean *to be part of an enterprise*, but I am not sure of what *useful enterprises* would mean, in the context of the sentence.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can't 'do endeavour', just like you can't 'do walk'. You can 'endeavour', or indeed be part of 'an endeavour'.

As kiamlaluno says, an endeavour is an enterprise or undertaking. So to be part of an endeavour is to be part of an enterprise; in this context, part of a group effort to achieve something.

Comment: Just feel strange. hand can be part of body, because they are all a kind of being. effort/endeavor is not a being, why human being can be part of an effort/endeavor?

Comment: In the same way they can be part of a project, or a football team, or a family. 'Part' doesn't always mean physically attached. In this case 'being part of' means 'making a contribution to'.

Comment: @lovespring:  In this context, the noun *endeavor* should be seen as a group, or collective, that works towards a common goal.  You could rephrase the original quote as, "the students will identify useful, *directed group activities* they can be a part of."

Comment: @lovespring:  speaking of _hand_, you could also say the students will [_have a hand in_](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+hand+in) the endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

"Be part of" is simply informal language for "participate in".